# ¿Qué es un archivo .WSDL y como implementarlo en mi proyecto?

Tags: webservice, wsdl, net, soapui

Hace unos días una compañía me envió un archivo `.WSDL`, quisiera poder agregar ,realizar pruebas y acceder a los métodos de este servicio desde mi proyecto.

He trabajado con **Servicios web**, pero siempre me daban el `endPoint`, por lo cual solo tenia que agregar la referencia del servicio al proyecto y podía acceder a los métodos, pero en este caso me enviaron el archivo `WSDL`.

Agrego algo de lo que he intentado:

Agregue el archivo que me enviaron al **`SOAP`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me arroja estos métodos,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema surge al momento de agregarlos a mi proyecto, cuando tengo que agregar la referencia al servicio no se como hacerlo, ya que en el **`soap`** cargo el archivo no una **`url`**.

Quiero saber cual seria el paso para poder agregar ese servicio a mi proyecto ?

Comment: Esta pregunta está siendo discutida en [meta]. Véase https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4295/65

Comment: Importante revisar [ask], como se indica en el documento: "Busca, e investiga", de hecho la pregunta que seleccionaste como solución es una traducción de este documento: https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**¿Qué es un WSDL?**

Según la documentación de [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html):

*"WSDL: Web Service Description Language por sus siglas en ingles o lenguaje de descripción de servicio web, en español. Es un lenguaje de definición basado en XML. Se utiliza para describir la funcionalidad de un servicio web basado en SOAP.*

*Los archivos WSDL son fundamentales para probar servicios basados ​​en SOAP. SoapUI utiliza archivos WSDL para generar solicitudes de prueba, aserciones y servicios simulados. Los archivos WSDL definen varios aspectos de los mensajes SOAP:*

*- Si algún elemento o atributo puede aparecer varias veces*

*- Los elementos y atributos requeridos u opcionales*

*- Un orden específico de elementos, si es necesario*

*Puede considerar un archivo WSDL como un contrato entre el proveedor y el consumidor del servicio."*

Te comparto el link de descarga [Download the Most Advanced API Testing Tool on the Market](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html)

Una vez que tengas instalado la aplicación de SoapUI y siguiendo la documentación [Getting Started  WSDL](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/getting-started.html), a continuación coloco los pasos para abrir tu archivo WSDL:

*1. Seleccione la opción "Nuevo proyecto" en el menú Archivo, que abrirá el siguiente cuadro de diálogo:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*2. Pegue la ruta WSDL http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl en el campo WSDL / WADL inicial (el nombre del proyecto se extraerá de esto) y presione OK. SoapUI creará el proyecto con el WSDL importado. Vaya directamente a la primera solicitud "Solicitud 1" generada para la operación Agregar y haga doble clic en ella, se abrirá la siguiente ventana:*

*Es importante que consideres que este es ejemplo de la documentación de SoapUI. Tu WSDL puede tener N operaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*3. Ahora deberá ingresar dos valores enteros y presionar la flecha verde en la parte superior izquierda para enviar la solicitud al servicio de destino, lo que le devolverá una respuesta:*

*Recuerda que tu request será diferente por lo que deberás ingresar otros datos, de igual forma recibirás otra respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Esta publicación es una traducción de : https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html , es recomendable dar crédito al autor**, revisa [answer]. El OP también pregunta "¿Cómo puedo ejecutar este archivo o verlo en un proyecto?".

Comment: Gracias por la observación, he editado la respuesta.

Comment: ese mismo XML, puedes copiarlo y agregarlo a POSTMAN con la url que se encuentra y funcionara de la misma manera, comento esto porque la pregunta se va mas a soapUI y no a el uso de WSDL

Answer (score 3):

El `wsdl` es algo asi como el instructivo del servicio que vas a consumir.
Dentro del `wsdl` vienen sus endpoints o metodos que puedes consumir, asi como la respuesta y lo que debes de enviar para poder consumir ese endpoint.

El formato es en `XML`, dentro de tu proyecto de .net puedes agregarlo como una referencia de servicio, poniendo tu url del `wsdl`.

Aqui puedes ver un ejemplo
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/452cfaf5-1e49-4875-a565-b430f9a1000d/implementar-y-consumir-un-wsdl-de-sap-en-c-web-service?forum=netfxwebes

Puedes utilizar SoapUI tambien o postman, ya que al final es un simple XML